# How to make &nbsp; same width as regular space?

Tags: html, css, fonts, space

When learning about HTML I thought   and `&nbsp;` had the same width but the following example show this does not hold.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</html>
<body style="font-family: Charter">
   Foo Foo&nbsp;Foo
</body>
```

The spaces are the same for most fonts, but not Charter for instance (it's pretty easy to find other examples). Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

From chapter 6 of [the Unicode specification](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/):

> No-Break Space. U+00A0 no-break space (NBSP) is the nonbreaking counterpart of U+0020 space. It has the same width, but behaves differently for line breaking.

If the width of a space and a non-breaking space is different in a given font, then it is a bug in that font and there isn't much you can do beyond changing fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can always change the font-size of the individual space

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</html>
<body style="font-family: Charter">
   Foo Foo<span style='font-size:10px;'>&nbsp;</span>Foo
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue when using a specific font but didn't want to change it. I came up with this solution:

Instead of one non-breaking space NBSP, you need to insert 2 compressed non-breaking spaces NNBSP (NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE - U+202F)